# npm publish ignores files inside node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

I've created npm package. In this package I'm using some modules which I put to node_modules to be able to require them as "modules", for example I have modules node_modules/my-module.js which I require in my code as require('my-module'). Now I do "npm publish" and then in another project I do "npm i" to install my module. It is installed but there are no my modules which I put to node_modules. I tried to add the next lines to .gitignore and to .npmignore, but it did not help:

node_modules/*

!node_modules/my-module.js

what do I do wrong?

Comment: Are these additional node_modules in your package.json file?

Comment: no, it is not modules from npm repository, it is my modules which I put to node_modules to be able to require them in modules style, not using relative or absolute paths

Answer (score 5):

I believe that all files in `node_modules/` are ignored by NPM, so setting rules for `node_modules` in `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` will have no effect.

> Additionally, everything in node_modules is ignored, except for bundled dependencies. npm automatically handles this for you, so don't bother adding node_modules to .npmignore.

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me why you want to have a package in the `node_modules` directory and not in the `package.json` file, but the short answer is that it's not possible, because [that directory will be always ignored](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package), as gauge said.

So there's two ways to go, you can put those modules in another directory and require it from his relative path or you publish those in NPM and then you require them from the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using something like:

```
!node_modules/
node_modules/*
!node_modules/my-module.js
```

I have that in a gitignore of mine and it has allowed publishing.

Comment: I tried
node_modules/*
!node_modules/my-module.js

I'll try tomorrow to add !node_modules/ as you wrote